# Чем лучше заменить расплодившиеся тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> Его <Пауля Клее> друг и товарищ по размышлениям, вскоре ключевая фигура европейской
>   живописи – Джорджо де Кирико в продолжении этой мысли – смещения
>   визуального с привычной позиции – открывает страницу *метафизической
>   живописи,* влияние которой испытают течения дадаистов, сюрреалистов и
>   всяких других художественных объединений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Джорджо де Кирико, его друг и товарищ по размышлениям **и** вскоре ключевая фигура европейской **масштаба**, **в продолжение** этой мысли – смещения визуального с привычной позиции – открывает страницу метафизической живописи, влияние которой испытают течения дадаистов, сюрреалистов и всяких других художественных объединений.

**Пояснение**

1) Первое тире обычно используется для обособления приложения со значением причины, а здесь такого значения нет. Поэтому имя собственное ставим на первое место.

2) Союз И позволяет убрать запятую.

3) Обратите внимание на падеж ***в продолжение***, мне кажется, что здесь должен быть  В.п. со значением "чтобы продолжить эту мысль".

4) Повтор слова ***живописи*** надо как-то убрать.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, так (без изменения авторских слов):

Джорджо де Кирико, его <Пауля Клее> друг и товарищ по размышлениям (вскоре ключевая фигура европейской живописи), в продолжении этой мысли – смещения визуального с привычной позиции – открывает страницу метафизической живописи, влияние которой испытают течения дадаистов, сюрреалистов и всяких других художественных объединений.